# A pointer have the good address but doesn't show the real information

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with pointers, when i create this objects i can see their correct address and i can access to the information.

```
World::World() {
    //Create Areas
    Area salaEst("East Room", "The East Room");
    Area salaWest("West Room", "The West Room");

    //Create Links
    salaEst.setDirection('w',&salaWest);
    salaWest.setDirection('e',&salaEst);

    //Player stats
    actual = &salaEst;

    //Prints
    salaEst.getArea();
    actual->getArea();

    cout << "East: " << &salaEst << "\nWest: " << &salaWest << "\nActual: " << actual << endl;
}
```

What I see in the console is:

```
East: 0x7fff5086c6e8
West: 0x7fff5086c648
Actual: 0x7fff5086c6e8
East Room
The East Room
East Room
The East Room
```

But if I want to see that information in an another function, for example in this one:

```
void World::actualArea() {
    cout << "Get actual Address Area: " << actual << endl;
    actual->getArea();
}
```

It shows the correct address too but `getArea` don't return correct information:

```
Get actual Address Area: 0x7fff5086c6e8

ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP?
ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP??ɆP?hɆP??ɆP??ɆP?
```

This part of the code is in the `Area` class:

```
Area::Area(string name, string description) {
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
}

void Area::getArea() {
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << description << endl;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: salaEst and salaWest are temporary variables in World contructor. After the scope of the function ends, actual will be pointing to the correct address, which will contain garbage.

Comment: `getArea` is a bad name for a function that prints something. Call it `printArea`.

Comment: `i can see their correct address`  A pointer that has an address that "looks correct" does not determine the validity of what is located at the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your variables are destroyed at the end of `World::World`. So, your pointer is invalid: this is an UB (Undefined behavior).